# docker-compose volumes not persisting after executing "docker-compose down"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker project which uses docker-compose to stand up an API container and a database container. I also have it setup to create volumes for `uploads` and `logs`.  When I build a new image, and then stand it up using `docker-compose up`, any data that was previously in the `logs` or `uploads` ceases to exist, but the data in our `db-data` volume persists.  What do I need to change in my process and/or config to preserve the data in those other two volumes?

Here's how we stand up the docker:

```
docker-compose down
docker build -t api:latest .
docker save -o api.tar api:latest postgres:14
docker load -i api.tar
docker-compose up -d
```

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM cupy/cupy AS deps
COPY nodesource_setup.sh .
RUN bash nodesource_setup.sh
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install libssl-dev ca-certificates cmake nodejs libgl-dev libglib2.0-0 -y
RUN pip3 install opencv-python python-dotenv

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./python ./ml_services/
COPY ./api/ .
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source only when needed
FROM deps AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=deps /app .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
RUN npm run build

FROM deps AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/ml_services ./ml_services
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/.env.production.local ./.env
COPY --from=builder /app/prisma ./prisma
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next

RUN mkdir -p /logs
RUN mkdir -p /uploads

RUN chown -R nextjs ./ /logs /uploads

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "deploy"]
```

And the `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    env_file: .env.production.local
    container_name: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready --username=autocal && psql --username=autocal --list"
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 20
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
    image: api:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on: [database]
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
          - driver: nvidia
            count: all
            capabilities: [gpu]
    volumes:
      - uploads:/uploads
      - logs:/logs

volumes:
  db-data:
  uploads:
  logs:
```

Comment: Are you sure your app does save under _/uploads_ and _/logs_ and not _/app/logs_ and _/app/uploads_? What you could do is `docker compose up -d && docker exec api touch /uploads/test && docker compose down && docker compose up && docker compose run api ls -la /uploads` to confirm your volumes are indeed working. If that's the case, then the issues lies you inr api not in your docker compose setup.

Comment: We have verified that the data is being saved to `/logs` and `/uploads`, and not `/app/logs` or `/app/uploads`

Comment: Find the volume names with `docker volume ls` and then do `docker run --rm -v <volume name>:/app alpine ls -lR /app` to check the content of the volume.

Comment: I don't think this comes from your docker config either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you writing `logs` and `uploads` in `/logs` and `/uploads` in your API code.

It might be the case it is being written it in `~/logs` and `~/uploads` (in the home directory of execution user).

Try to use absolute path not the relative path in your code.

Please go through node js docs around the path module https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely ended up being a code issue in the API layer. Sigh. Thanks all.